# Trigger jQuery on Bootstrap dropdown toggle

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I made a bootply that won't generate a link, so here's my settings that I threw in there.

I want to have jQuery add a class to another div when this dropdown is triggered, and remove the class when the dropdown is hidden.

CSS:

```
.halfOpacity
  {
    opacity: .5;
  }
#switchMenu
  {
    top: 100px;
  }
#siteData
  {
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: #000;
  }
```

Javascript:

```
$('#switchDropdown').on('show.bs.dropdown', function(){
  $('#siteData').addClass('halfOpacity');
});
$('#switchDropdown').on('hide.bs.dropdown', function(){
  $('#siteData').removeClass('halfOpacity');
});
```

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="navbar-brand dropdown-toggle mobile-footer-brand" data-toggle="dropdown" id='switchDropdown'>Test Link</a>

<ul class='dropdown-menu' id='switchMenu'>
  <li>HORRAY!!!!</li>
</ul>

<div id='siteData'>Some Stuff<br>Moar stuff<br>Even moar stuffs</div>
```

Right now the jQuery never gets called based off of the actions that Bootstrap says happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered my own question with reading documentation more clearly.

### Events

**All dropdown events are fired at the `.dropdown-menu`'s parent element.**

[Bootstrap Documentation Here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns)

The following changes fixed it for me:

Javascript:

```
$('#wrap').on('show.bs.dropdown', function(){
  $('#siteData').addClass('halfOpacity');
});
$('#wrap').on('hide.bs.dropdown', function(){
  $('#siteData').removeClass('halfOpacity');
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id='wrap'>
<a href="#" class="navbar-brand dropdown-toggle mobile-footer-brand" data-toggle="dropdown" id='switchDropdown'>Test Link</a>

<ul class='dropdown-menu' id='switchMenu'>
  <li>HORRAY!!!!</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id='siteData'>Some Stuff<br>Moar stuff<br>Even moar stuffs</div>
```